# Erratic results with host discovery using nmap

Tags: linux, networking

Based on the manual, `nmap -sn` Run as privilege user is supposed to perform a host discovery on a subnet using ARP.

I have difficulties making sense of the results. The command:

```
nmap -sn 192.168.69.1/24
```

does not always return all hosts on the network reachable via ping. In general it returns all hosts wired to the network, but the hosts connected via wifi sometimes are detected sometimes are not.

If however I explicitly target an host connected via wifi, e.g. 192.168.69.32, this reliably detect the host all the times:

```
nmap -sn 192.168.69.32
```

If instead I use ping, the command works all the times, but it is much slower.

```
nmap -sn --send-ip 192.168.69.1/24
```

Is there any way to make the ARP version of the command more reliable?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be more down to the protocol being used, and characteristics of the transmission medium than problems with the application. (...)